# Gmail in Firefox: German keyboard shortcut for indenting a list

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

This question is about Gmail's keyboard shortcuts with a German keyboard layout.

In Chrome, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ß</kbd>/<kbd>´</kbd> (the two keys next to Backspace) to reduce/increase the indent of a numbered or bulleted list. That does not work in Firefox. Pressing either key combination does nothing.

**Is there any way I can to enable this functionality in Firefox?**